# Accessing IIS site externally

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, windows-server-2012, iis

We have 2 servers, a **Domain (Server 1)** and an **Application (Server 2)** server. We are attempting to open an port on the Application Server to be accessed externally.

**Server 1** is running Windows Essentials 2012, and **Server 2** is running Windows Essentials 2012-R2. Because they are on the same network, **Server 2** has not been configured properly as an Essentials Server (the only roles it is using currently is Application Server roles) to remove any possible conflicts with **Server 1**.

We have an IIS set up on **Server 1**, using remote web access, that can be used to access the server externally. The IIS on **Server 2** has not been modified (it is still displaying the default page), and we cannot access it externally, which is the goal.

What we have tried so far:

- Open an external port (8080) through the Router (D-Link DSL-2730B) and link it to an internal port (80) on **Server 2**

  - We have done the same for **Server 1**, which does work (have tried multiple ports, eg. 8080 - 8084)
- Tried disabling windows firewalls completely on both servers
- Ran a Telnet on an opened port (8086) to **Server 1** (went through fine)
- Ran a Telnet on an opened port (8087) to **Server 2** (timed out)
- Ran a Telnet on a port that was not set up (connection refused)

Here are our site binding for **Server 2**

[image]

Here are the current open ports set up in the D-Link

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working!

I ran an `ipconfig`, and it showed this:

```
Default Gateway.....0.0.0.0 
                    192.168.1.1
```

To remedy this, using Powershell I removed the Default Gateway:

```
route delete 0.0.0.0
```

Then I re-added it as the only Gateway:

```
route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1
```

Now I can access the IIS from Server 2 externally through the port the port we have defined.